# Comment traduire « Get the fuck out » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, vulgarité

Je me demande comment on traduit « Get the fuck out » ou même « Get the fuck out of here ».

Cette phrase est souvent dite dans l'émission « The Sopranos ». Des fois ça semble vouloir dire qu'il veut que la personne parte. Certaines fois ils le disent comme s'ils ne croyaient pas l'autre personne.

Y a-t-il une phrase ou une expression qui voudrait dire la même chose ?

Comment: "get the fuck outta here" as heard in The Sopranos is the same thing as "No kidding", but ruder and more macho and from New Jersey. Aren't you interested in the real meaning??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quelques traductions possibles :

> Dégage !
>
> Casse-toi !
>
> Fous le camp !
>
> Barre-toi !
>
> Tire-toi !

Rajouter ***"de là"*** pour ***"of here"***, par example ***"Dégage de là !"***.

J'aurais une préférence pour ***"Fous le camp !"*** car ***"fous"*** remplace bien ***"fuck"***.

Comment: C'est *camp*, sans *s*, non?

Comment: Et concernant la 2eme partie de la question ? "Certaines fois ils le disent comme s'ils ne croyaient pas l'autre personne"

Comment: @Sander Oui évidemment, au temps pour moi.

Comment: @Random Hors context je ne saurais te dire. J'imagine qu'un individu qui comprend qu'on lui raconte des bobards pourrait dire grossièrement "Casse-toi !" (ou pire "Va te faire foutre !")

Comment: Pour le cas ou il ne croit pas l'autre personnage, ça veut dire : "Tu sors !"

Comment: Pourrait on également dire *d'ici* au lieu de *de là* dans ce contexte?

Comment: @Sander Il y a plus de dédain dans "de là" que dans "d'ici", du fait que *là* peut être un peu n'importe où. Je pense donc que "de là" convient mieux.

Comment: Vous vous trompez tous. Désolée.

Answer (score 5):

Pour la deuxième partie de la question, si mon interlocuteur me raconte des choses dont je ne crois pas un mot, et dans un contexte familier/grossier je dirais:

> Arrête tes conneries !

Dans un autre registre (qui s'éloigne un peu de la question originale) :

> Balivernes !

Comment: "Balivernes !" n'est pas seulement d'un autre registre, il est aussi fortement daté selon moi.

Comment: J'utilise cette expression assez souvent, particulièrement quand la poudre de perlinpinpin ne marche pas.

Comment: Oui, et ce ne pas en anglais fous le camp, ici. Par contre, cela peut aussi signaler la surprise, ce qui n'est pas arrête tes conneries. Autrement dit,un synomyme pour: no kidding.

Answer (score 2):

Ces trois phrases sont des traductions possibles :

> - Casse-toi !
> - Barre-toi !
> - Tire-toi !

Je ne connais pas de traductions plus proches que celles-ci, mais je pense qu'elles expriment bien l'idée du locuteur voulant, en le disant d'une manière plutôt grossière, que l'autre s'en aille.

Comment: Et concernant la 2eme partie de la question ? "Certaines fois ils le disent comme s'ils ne croyaient pas l'autre personne"

Comment: Je ne connais pas d'expression pour cette signification. On pourrait la traduire par *Tu rigoles?!* ou une telle expression.

Answer (score 2):

Pour sens #2, dans l'Oise j'entend "[Mon cul](http://en.bab.la/dictionary/french-english/mon-cul)" assez. souvent quand je dis n'importe quoi. (Babla Dictionary)

"Mon cul" n'a pas de rapport directe  avec sens #1, mais dans la phrase "[parle/cause a mon cul, ma tete est malade](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/cause-%C3%A0-mon-cul-ma-t%C3%AAte-est-malade.826063/)", le sens de "degage, je ne veux rien entendre de toi ni de tes conneries" est present, d'apres moi. (Word reference)

Comment: Exactement. Dans The Sopranos, c'est une expression new yorkaise par la biais de New Jersey and cela n'a absolumment rien à voir avec fous le camp, qui, je dois dire, se dit de la même façon....

Answer (score 2):

Quebec context (scram = *anglicism*)

> [Aweille](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/aweille), [scram](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/scram)
>
> [Décrisse](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9crisser) d'[icitte](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/icitte)